# How to bump up text?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to bump up my email to go right below my name, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. Google was no help. This is only a practice page. I am learning at the moment.

here is my current css and html

```css
   #email {
     position: relative;
     margin: -19px;
     right: -100px;
   }
   div:nth-child(2) {
     border: 2px solid black;
     width: 400px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background-color: #EEE0E5;
   }
   #name {
     border: 2px solid black;
     width: 370.5px;
     position: relative;
     color: red;
     padding: 1em;
     background-color: #EEE0E5;
     border-radius: 5px;
     text-align: center;
     padding-left: 10px;
   }
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="name">Marika Devan</h1>

  <a href="mailto:marikadevan@gmail.com">
    <p id="email">marikadevan@gmail.com</p>
  </a>



</div>
<div class="right">
  <h3>Objective:</h3>
  <p>to become a tour guide.</p>
  <h4>Experience</h4>
  <p>tour guide</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Take groups of students around the museum</li>
    <li>assist at the different exhibits</li>
    <li>answering questions anyone may have</li>
  </ul>
  <p>pizza maker</p>
  <ul>
    <li>make pizza</li>
    <li>assist customer</li>
    <li>chill by the oven</li>
  </ul>



</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the styling for the H1 into the header div, and then remove your email styling.

Will need a bit of tweaking to get it all lined up nicely with the bottom part of your HTML, but your email is now below your name
http://jsfiddle.net/hrcm1tfb/

HTML

```
<div id="header">
  <h1 id="name">Marika Devan</h1>
  <a href="mailto:marikadevan@gmail.com"><p id="email">marikadevan@gmail.com</p></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header{
border: 2px solid black;
width: 370.5px;
position: relative;
color: red;
padding: 1em;
background-color: #EEE0E5;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the styles you added to the #name ID for your name.

If you wrapped the email and your name in a div.

http://jsfiddle.net/u1k00Lnr/

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="name">
      <h1 id="name">Marika Devan</h1>
      <a href="mailto:marikadevan@gmail.com"><p id="email">marikadevan@gmail.com</p></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

I also renamed the #name ID to a class .name

```
   .name {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 370.5px;
    position: relative;
    color: red;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #EEE0E5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you apply your styles to `#header` instead of the `h1`:

```
#header{
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 370.5px;
  position: relative;
  color: red;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #EEE0E5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#name {
 //add styles you want
}


#email {
  font-size: 14px;
 //add styles you want
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oz9x8hLa/1/)

I would also remove:

```
position: relative;
margin: -19px;
right: -100px;
```

from `#email` there is no reason to set these. `text-align:center` which is already added to the parent will center the email address on its own.